# Trying to return emails within past 24 hours using ExchangeLib

Tags: python, email, exchange-server, exchangelib

I'm trying to use ExchangeLib to return all emails within an inbox within the past 24 hours. I currently have it set up to return the most recent email in the inbox, I just need help with the 24 hours part. Here is what I have so far:

```
credentials = Credentials('My@email', 'password')
account = Account('My@email', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:1]:
    print(item.subject, item.sender.email_address)

    html = item.unique_body

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for span in soup.find_all('font'):
        return(item.subject, item.sender.email_address, span.text)
```

I've been trying to look up references on how to go about this, but I'm honestly not finding much. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a greater-than filter on the `datetime_received` field:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from exchangelib import UTC_NOW

since = UTC_NOW() - timedelta(hours=24)
for item in account.inbox.all()\
        .filter(datetime_received__gt=since)\
        .order_by('-datetime_received'):
    # Do something
```